# Laravel - Getting "1067 Invalid Default Value" for unsignedInteger on migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to run a migration on Laravel for creating a new table, but I'm getting this error:

**Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'tracked_product_id'**

I understand there is an issue with the first *unsignedInteger* line - I have attempted to change this default value but it returns the same error when attempting to migrate.

Here is the up function that I am trying to migrate:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tracked_product_notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('tracked_product_id', true)->default(0);
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id', true)->default(0);
        $table->string('note')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('deleted_at');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change it to `$table->unsignedInteger('tracked_product_id')->default(null);` or `$table->unsignedInteger('tracked_product_id')->nullable();`

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to reply at the time. This fixed my issue, thanks Droid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to :

```
$table->unsignedInteger('tracked_product_id')->default(null);
```

or

```
$table->unsignedInteger('tracked_product_id')->nullable();
```